# What is the better way to access to related graphic objects

Tags: javascript, html, 2d-games, pixi.js

I am asking specifically for `javacript` and especially `pixijs` canvas-webgl library but the question could be easily generalized for making games.

I am developing a simple 2D game. In a game there are various objects that are rendered to be visible on screen and usually they are related to each other. For example, there are 5 enemy characters, each has a weapon, a name text, a hit-point bar, etc. to show on screen together.

To group all these graphic objects typically there is a `Container`, i.e. `Enemy`, and its objects are put in `children` array.

**But then how do I access to one specific object later in the code?** `Enemies[3].children[0]` does not mean any thing, indices could be changed. What I do want to get is, for example, the weapon with id `weapon-1` of the enemy with attribute `race=hobbit`.

In **pixijs** I could not find an example to do that. In **Kineticjs** there was `find` method. In pixijs neither did I see that.

I think 3 ways to achieve this in javascript (with pixijs) :

- Write a general `find` method which allows to search for an object depends on its attributes, and every time when I need the object, make a search within the `Container`. This would be like in **KineticJs**. But how efficient would be?
- Keeping a huge javascript `map` with all graphic objects, then reach immediately to the object that I want using its variable name, ie, `map.stage.enemies.hobbits[0].weapons.weapon1`. But how could I maintain this? Seems easily going out of control. Moreover, still there is need a `find` function to search against dynamically changing attributes.
- Similar to the second; adding the child to the parent as a variable, ie, `var weapon = new Weapon(); enemy.addChild(weapon); enemy.weapon1 = weapon;`, then easily reach to the object later, knowing its variable name. But, the object is already kept in `children`, is there need to maintain again in a second way?

It seems to me better the first one. But,

**How do you do this better? How do you organize this? Is there a better 4th way?**

Thanks.

Comment: Without a doubt your option two would be my first choice, could you expand on "dynamically changing attributes."?

Comment: @KФ For example, when it is clicked on an object, we could change "isClicked" attribute to true, and then we could want to search for the "clicked" children. Yes, with a mvc model this could be on the model part, but imagine such attribute we want to keep on the graphic object itself.